# Download all group files using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to use Facebook Grahpi API to download all files from FB group. I'm member of this group, and moreover I'm its admin.

The endopoint that I had been trying to use was

```
/v2.6/{group-id}/files
```

I'm working with Facebook Graph API Explorer so I don't have to pass access token manually. Additionally, my token has 'user_managed_groups' permission. Everything works quiet good with other endpoints, for example:

```
/docs, /members
```

Endpoint /files returns JSON with empty data array.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Works fine for me, as long as I am the group admin.

Comment: That's all I got: [link](http://i.imgur.com/Q1CfbJU.png)

Comment: And there have been actual files uploaded to this group? This endpoint is for files that have been uploaded via “More -> Add File” only; it is not supposed to return f.e. photos or videos uploaded to the group. So when you select the “Files” tab on the group page, you actually see files listed there?

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of files.

Comment: Then I suggest you file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs